# How can I make mirror server of ROS for local network?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone give instruction of making local ROS mirror?
Everytime I install ROS from Willow Garage server it is bit slow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11857/how-can-i-make-mirror-server-of-ros-for-local-network?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/131/how-do-i-set-up-a-ros-mirror.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1